# Setting counter to each box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few boxes which when clicked, it will shake mildy. The more you click, the more harder it will shake. The box will sort of "drop" down after 10 continuous clicks. All the boxes does not share the same counter with each other.

I have tried the following code but I can't get the counter to work.

Any kind souls can help me out here?

Thanks in advance guys!

```
$(".gift").each(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $(this).click(function(){
        if(i == 0){
            TweenMax.fromTo(this, 1, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            i++;
        }
        console.log(i);
    });
});
```

Here is my codepen : http://codepen.io/Dr3am3rz/pen/ggPYEO

Comment: `if(i=0){` should be `if(i==0){`. You have to check. Now you're just asigning.

Comment: what is TweenMax.

Comment: You could have spent a bit more effort at least adding the libraries to codepen so that it runs, and explaining where TweenMax comes from

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLQEGr

Comment: So sorry everyone, apologize for missing out including the libraries in codepen. TweenMax is a function used in Greensock plugins.

Comment: Thanks Banzay! =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare i to zero, but not assign.

Second is you need to move `i++` out of `if(){}` statement.

Third you need to link required libraries correctly.

```
$(".gift").each(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $(this).click(function(){
            if(i===0){
                TweenMax.fromTo(this, 1, {x:-1}, {x:1, ease:RoughEase.ease.config({strength:8, points:5, template:Linear.easeNone, randomize:false}) , clearProps:"x"})
            }
                i++;
      $(this).html("counter = "+i);
        });
    });
```

A result is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLQEGr

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am still confused about "=", "==" and "===" =x

Comment: As far as I know  an operator `==` is true when values are equal , and operator `===` is true when values and types are equal.

Comment: I see. Thanks! =D